# I have try to install pip install mysqlclient on mac give some error?

Tags: python, django

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/2b/1sy6xpk55qz87d1dx31qn92w0000gn/T/pip-install-ke4S5K/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 51, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2b/1sy6xpk55qz87d1dx31qn92w0000gn/T/pip-install-ke4S5K/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `brew install mysql-connector-c`. If you don't have brew installed, install it with `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Also, you should switch development from Legacy Python, i.e. Python 2, to Python 3, since it will not be supported past January 1st, 2020.